# Is it possible to embed xml xsl transformed into a html in an inline matter

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am wondering if there is possible such situation where I can place inline xml linked with xsl into the body of html, like:

```
<html>
 <body>
  text
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="articles.xsl"?>
  <articles>
   <article title="title"/>
  </articles>
  text
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping it into an `<object>` ?

Comment: Why can't you simply put **all** your HTML code in the XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: Stefan what do you mean by saying to wrap an xml into an html tag `<object>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Kay suggested, you can embed the XML in XHTML and apply the stylesheet to the entire document. Then you can apply an XSL transformation to the entire document, applying the identity transform to all HTML elements and specific templates to the embedded non-HTML elements.

Here is an example:

**Input XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ie8fix.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    text
    <articles xmlns="">
      <article title="title"/>
    </articles>
    text
  </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="articles">
    <div class="articles">
      <h1>articles</h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="article" mode="transform"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="article" mode="transform">
    <article><!-- HTML5 article element -->
      <h2><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="transform"/>
    </article>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ie8fix.xsl"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    text
    <div class="articles">
         <h1>articles</h1>
         <article>
            <h2>title</h2>
         </article>
      </div>
    text
  </body>
</html>
```

Another option would be to transform the XML after loading the page using JavaScript and `XSLTProcessor`.

Comment: it will carry behind the same disadvantages as mentioned in the comment at Michael Kay post

Answer (score 0):

See section 2.4 of

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-html-xml-tf-report-20120209/

The two approaches suggested there are

(a) Put the XML inside a `script` element

(b) Use XHTML.

Direct nesting of XML inside the HTML as in your example is not advised because the HTML parser will treat the XML as bad HTML, and try to repair it.

Comment: the a) solution will not be traceable by search engines. The b) solution is better but it will force me to interfer into the dynamically page serving mechanism such as php and partially change the global idea of service.

Comment: In theory option (a) certainly is traceable, but in practice, search engines might just ignore the XML that is embedded in the HTML or rank the page lower because it's "not well coded" according to HTML standards. (I've no experience with SEO, but I remember that Google wanted to make page quality/accessibility one criterion for the page rank.)